# How to change text color in cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, cmd

I need to change the colors. Input - one color, output - second color.
Look image:

[image]

Comment: Impossible to answer this question, since you didn't tell us what programming language you are using to write to the command prompt.

Comment: i use data base sqlite in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative program where you can choose the color on the input, output and errors. Take Command.